# Discarding A record responses - when querying a DNS entry returns both A and AAAA records

Tags: ipv6, internal-dns, ipv4

I have a linux system with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

I want to reach an external system by way of a DNS entry.

This DNS entry returns both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (A and AAAA)

Is there something I can do, maybe with dnsmasq?, to discard the A response so my system tries to reach the remote system over IPv6?

Comment: Resolving this issue at the DNS level is an unnecessary band-aid. The root cause of the problem is in your `/etc/gai.conf` file. Googling around `linux dual stack prefer IPv6` should help you resolve this. Also, this is worth a read if you're using private IPv6 addresses https://thomas-leister.de/en/lxd-prefer-ipv6-outgoing/

Comment: That works fine for the underlying OS, but services like JVM do not respect this and will still use IPv4

Comment: The JVM should also call `getaddrinfo`: cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464464/11748454)

Comment: It depends on the application you are using. But before anything you have to be sure that you actually have a working IPv6 stack (public routable address). Does `ping 2606:4700:4700::1001` work? Does `ping one.one.one.one` send packages to the ipv6 address?

Comment: Yes, the IPv6 stack undeniably works. We can reach internal and external hosts without issue

Comment: You mentioned JVM. If you have a particular application you understandably want working over IPv6, please edit your question to add the operating system and any network stack the app uses.

Comment: There are MANY applications.. That's why I was going for a system wide approach.

Comment: The approach given by @slightly_toasted **is** a system wide approach. Only applications which do not use **glibc** or use obsolete functions are not affected by `/etc/gai.conf`. Can you add to your question a list/example of misbehaving applications?